# Is it possible for WordPress to get user information from an existing, non-MySQL database?

Tags: wordpress

I'm considering installing WordPress at `example.com/blog`.  However, `example.com` functions mainly as a forum/bulletin board and thus has a user database.  I'd like users of `example.com` to be able to login to the WordPress install with their existing credentials.

Is that in any way possible?

This is further complicated by the fact that `example.com` is written in .NET and uses a Microsoft SQL Server database.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about administering a self-hosted application.

Comment: @AlE. you're absolutely right. I agree it's off-topic, please feel free to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it but this plugin seems to be what you need: [External DB authentication](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/external-database-authentication/).

Answer (score -1):

Can the forum act as an OpenID provider? Wordpress accept OpenID logins (this requires a plugin). With a bit of a hack, you could tweak the OpenID login plugin so that instead of offering the normal options (standard login, OpenID URL), it immediately fills in the OpenID URL of the forum's OpenID endpoint, and then submits it. That means that no one ever sees the Wordpress login page: they're immediately redirected to the forum and then, if they're already signed in at the forum, they're redirected straight back to Wordpress, this time as logged in users. If they're not logged in at the forum, they'll log in there and continue back to Wordpress.

This requires that the forum implements OpenID in such a manner that everyone has the same endpoint. This is doable.